# Ошибка при запуске приложения

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Я понял, что программа не может что-то найти, sdk все есть, jdk 1.7. Раньше работал на eclipse и ничего подобного не встречал.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>     C:\Users\админ\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\админ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\админ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
> Error Code:
>     1
> Output:
>     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\Р°РґРјРёРЅ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
>         at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Р°РґРјРёРЅ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-62df87fcdfb79ea56359187f50d5e9605d1421a8.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Р°РґРјРёРЅ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-76c811416207bf176bba1e92edb1f6050ee29eb1.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Р°РґРјРёРЅ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-514b2ba3c557b15085209100f8098ab3497551f7.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Р°РґРјРёРЅ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-fad75407bd6f77ef2025873adc62262e0238dc56.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>     5 errors; aborting

Comment: киррилица в пути. Так нельзя.

Comment: @marsianen, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

99% кодировка. Перекиньте сдк куда нибудь, чтоб путь из англ букв был

> C:\Users\Р°РґРјРёРЅ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-76c811416207bf176bba1e92edb1f6050ee29eb1.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)